# Qlikview - change title in browser

Tags: browser, qlikview

when I run my app in server using access point I get this in browser (in title)

[image]

I want instead of that to write the name of my app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Settings - Document Properties` under the tab `General` you can change the `Title`.